# Creating "on the fly" images of graphs from data in PL/SQL

Tags: java, oracle, graph, plsql, analytics

I had an idea and wondered if anyone could point me at a good java lib to achieve this?
I've written a package that allows multiple sections of dynamic content to be added into emails and distributed to it's audiences as required. One requirement that has been mentioned in the past was to produce graphs in these emails. (We don't have Oracle BI, or the budget to buy it). I would like to consider adding graphs based on an object or data (Maybe a view object) that could be passed into a Java operation and produce a BLOB of data i could pass into the email and distribute? Running on Oracle 10g R2. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Can you create those graphs in advance, with some tool and have thme as images, before you send the e-mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use any Java library that can be loaded in the Database JVM.
I've used http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart a while ago and it worked quite well.
If you wanna go PL/SQL only this is also possible and this http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/blog/2005/november/22.html article might be a good start.